# InstallShield 2016 Build 32 bit exe

Tags: dll, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, installshield

I have an InstallShield project (2011) the UseDlls of 32 bit.
When I try to upgrade to InstallShield to 2016 - I get an error when I try to run the installation, of problem with loading the dll.

This dll is 32 bit specific, and I see that it has a problem to load it's dependencies because it's trying to find 64bit dlls instead of 32bit dlls.

How can I force the installation to work only with 32bit dlls?

Thanks,
Dudi

Comment: Assuming you're talking InstallScript's UseDLL, you've misdiagnosed the problem, as InstallScript's UseDLL support is 32-bit only. More likely it's having trouble locating the dependencies due to changes related to preventing binary planting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InstallShield UseDLL() doesn't find dll dependencies in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207371/installshield-usedll-doesnt-find-dll-dependencies-in-the-same-directory)